# Load only one gallery using Fancybox

Tags: jquery, load, fancybox, gallery

My website uses one image to load a gallery. In the old version of Fancybox, you used a .js-file to load the images and that worked fine. With the new one, I have to hide the images and every single image is loaded when the user visits my website.

How do I prevent that? The users should only load the images from the gallery they are visiting.

You can have a look at my website here: http://www.mogm.nl/2011.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to load all the images on the hidden `div` (there is not use for that), only the anchor, so this:

```
<div style="display:none">
 <a class="fancybox" rel="Rhodos11" href="http://www.mogm.nl/bilder/2011/rhodos11/rhodos1101.jpg"><img src="http://www.mogm.nl/bilder/2011/rhodos11/rhodos1101.jpg" /></a>
 ... etc
```

can be reduced to this:

```
<div style="display:none">
 <a class="fancybox" rel="Rhodos11" href="http://www.mogm.nl/bilder/2011/rhodos11/rhodos1101.jpg"></a>
 ... etc
```

that will reduce significantly the load page.

On the other hand, you can always use `ajax` to load the content of each gallery dynamically but you have to set the link reference to the images in any case either inside of a hidden `div` or an external file. Let me know if you prefer the second option and I will post a script I already have for that.

Comment: Thank you! :) That helped me a lot! According to Opera, the page went from loading 192 elements to just 14. Nice!